# Iframe 404 Error -- how to have a frame pop-up within the page?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to get an iframe to load in my page when a user clicks a link. The relevant parts of my code are here:

```
<a href='/flaggingCriteria.html' target='flaggingCriteria'>
```

This is within a google map info window... at the bottom of the page, I have:

```
<div>
    <iframe src="flaggingCriteria.html" name="flaggingCriteria" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
</div>
```

There is a flaggingCriteria.html file in the same folder.

At the bottom of my page, however, I have a "404 Not Found" error instead. Did I miss something obvious? Thanks..

Comment: The `/` at the beginning of your URL will tell the browser to start searching at the root of the original URL, not in the same directory (necessarily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your link like so:

```
<a href='flaggingCriteria.html' target='flaggingCriteria'>
```

The leading `/` is telling it to look in the server root and not the current location.

Answer (score 0):

well it's pretty obvious - your flaggingCriteria.html can't be opened - your link element href is targeting the root of your server, you might wanna check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Give the iframe a name

(iframe name=**'youriframe'** src='' ...>)

and add target='youriframe' to your link

e.g.: http://example.com/' target='**youriframe**'>Click!